# PHP PDF creation from Postscript and send in email as attatchment in runtime

Tags: php, pdf, email-attachments

- using php mailer to send email ..
- used

  ```
  $mail->AddStringAttachment($attachments, $name = 'Invoice_4675.pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
  ```

Getting this in `$attatchments` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Invoice_4675.pdf
            [1] => %PDF-1.6
%äãÏÒ
1 0 obj
[/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text]
endobj
4 0 obj
<>
stream
xœ
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
8
endobj
7 0 obj
<>
stream
ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿÛCÿÛCÿÀ3ðÿÄ  
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ    
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?þþ( OÆ¾8ð¿Ã¿ÝxŸÅú¬Z>hñB÷2G4Í%Ìä­½­¼ñË<÷°Âª©îN$zyFO™g¸êYvU†uqrMÙYY-äÛi$º¶Íðøjøª±£‡¦åQô_™åý¨>üA×-<7¡ë÷–úÖ ïŸe¬hÚ–•ö×\ŽÞæâ²f9£H¯!(UÝ¤ù¬º»Yug©‰áìÛ†ž2®ýš;´Óµü¯]4>ƒ¯†<@ €



          [2] => buffer
        )

)
```

- How to generate pdf from this using php and send in email as an attatchment ....

but not working ...

any guess how to do that.

Comment: can any one help me here please ,...

Comment: You should show us an [mvce] for more accurate help and advice; Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately i resolved my issue by my own :

$attachments = "My post script.";

$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachments, "test.pdf", "base64", "application/pdf");

Hope helps somebody.